# Unable to use date variable

Tags: powershell, date, get-winevent

I'm still quite new with PowerShell, and what I do right now if I have some requirements, I will search the web and modify the code to what I need.

Right now, I am trying to extract RDP user logins from our servers. I have managed to get some codes, updated it so I can run it remotely thru invoke-command. However, I am having issue with one of the variables, wherein if I put a value of a date, e.g. 1-Sep-2019 or 9/1/2019, the script works. But if I use (Get-Date).AddDays(-7), it won't work. I have been testing this script the whole afternoon yesterday, and for the life of me, I can't still make it work :(

This is the part of the code that I am having issues:

```
#$StartDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") #--> does not work
#$StartDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)   #--> does not work
#$StartDate = "1-Sep-2019"  #--> Works
$StartDate = "9/1/2019"  #--> Works
```

And here is the complete script that I am testing. Appreciate if someone can give some hint on how to make this work without using a static date. Thanks in advance for the help!

```
Start-Transcript -path "D:\temp\Get-User-Logins_$(Get-Date -f yyyyMMddHHmm).log"

$Computers = Get-Content "D:\temp\Server list.txt"

Write-Output "Processing the computers"

$LogEntries = Invoke-Command -Computername $Computers -Authentication NegotiateWithImplicitCredential -ThrottleLimit 10 -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue" -Scriptblock {
    # Get the date 7 days ago as start date
    #$StartDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") #--> does not work
    #$StartDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)   #--> does not work
    #$StartDate = "1-Sep-2019"  #--> Works
    $StartDate = "9/1/2019"  #--> Works

    $LogOutput = @()

    $LogFilter = @{
        LogName = 'Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager/Operational'
        ID = 22 
        StartTime = $StartDate
    }

    $LogOutput = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $LogFilter

    $LogOutput | Foreach { 
        $entry = [xml]$_.ToXml()
        [array]$EVOutput += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            TimeCreated = $_.TimeCreated
            User = $entry.Event.UserData.EventXML.User
            IPAddress = $entry.Event.UserData.EventXML.Address
            EventID = $entry.Event.System.EventID
            EventRecordID = $entry.Event.System.EventRecordID
            ServerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
        }        
    } 

    $EVOutput
}

Write-Output "Writing the output to the file"

$FilteredOutput += $LogEntries | Select ServerName, TimeCreated, User, IPAddress, EventRecordID, @{Name='Action';Expression={
            if ($_.EventID -eq '22'){"Shell start"}
    }
}


    $FilePath = "D:\temp\$(Get-Date -f yyyyMMddHHmm)_RDP_Report.csv"
    $FilteredOutput | Sort -Property ServerName, TimeCreated | Export-Csv $FilePath -NoTypeInformation

Write-Output "Writing File: $FilePath"
Write-Output "Done!"

Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: Please qualify "won't work", and "doesn't work" - do you get errors, unexpected results, no results?

Comment: Agreed. Are you receiving an error message(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure why using the variable $StartDate does not work for the hashtable, but I managed to finally found a solution for my requirement. In case someone else is interested, I did not use a separate hashtable variable anymore ($LogFilter in my script), and instead, use the following lines:

```
$StartDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
$LogOutput = Get-Winevent -logname Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager/Operational | where {$_.TimeCreated -gt $StartDate -and $_.Id -eq "22"}
```

I managed to get my required result with this, thus closing this post.